# PHP: Retrieve all possible options within a dropdown and select option for specific record

Tags: php

I am still really new to PHP, I am creating a page for updating a specific record. I have passed an ID into the URL of the page, and using the ID for getting specific data for that record.

The trouble I am having is with dropdown lists. I want to pull back all possible options for that dropdown (which comes from a different table) and I have this sorted.

```
$status_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT AssetStatus.AssetStatusTitle AS HardwareAssetAssetStatusTitle, HardwareAssetAssetStatusID FROM HardwareAsset INNER JOIN AssetStatus ON (AssetStatus.AssetStatusID = HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetStatusID) ORDER BY HardwareAssetAssetStatusTitle ASC";
$status = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $status_sql);
while($status_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($status)){
    echo "<option value='$status_option->HardwareAssetAssetStatusID'>".$status_option->HardwareAssetAssetStatusTitle."</option>";
}
```

The issue comes when i want to have an option already selected for that record. I know to get the specific option i need the following:

```
$status_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT AssetStatus.AssetStatusTitle AS HardwareAssetAssetStatusTitle, HardwareAssetAssetStatusID FROM HardwareAsset INNER JOIN AssetStatus ON (AssetStatus.AssetStatusID = HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetStatusID)  WHERE HardwareAssetID = '".$HardwareAssetID."'";
```

but how do i combine these both together? Having the selected option, selected on load by default, and all other options available when opening the dropdown.

I have spent a fair amount of time searching online, but I dont think I am searching for the right thing, as I havent really turned anything up. Any help appreciated.

Comment: use a ternary operator

Comment: after some research on ternary operators, got it thanks.

Comment: you're welcome Joel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to modify the original `SELECT`query and put `WHERE` clause in it. Simply change your `while` loop in the following way,

```
while($status_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($status)){
    $output = "<option value='$status_option->HardwareAssetAssetStatusID'";
    if($status_option->HardwareAssetAssetStatusID == $HardwareAssetID){
        $output .= " selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= ">".$status_option->HardwareAssetAssetStatusTitle."</option>";
    echo $output;
}
```